# Criterion for existence unique real solution of system of equations without solving

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

Suppose we have $n$ polynomial (of degree $2$) equation with $n$ unknown.

> Is there a criterion for existence unique real solution of this system of equation?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Are you saying you are given a polynomial of degree 2 with n variables (such as $x^2+xy-y^2+y$ for 2 variables)?

Comment: yes. what is unclear?

Comment: The phrase "$n$ polynomial" is not familiar to me and is thus unclear. You also mention a "system" of equations without saying there is more than one polynomial. So you could have meant $n$ polynomials, each of degree 2. But now you seem to agree that there is only one such polynomial.